# Save "Visual VoiceMail" recordings on iPhone to sound files

Tags: osx, ios, voice-recording

Looking for software to extract voice mail recordings on iPhone to be saved as regular sound files. Want to move the sound files to my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

## iExplorer

The [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) app from [Macroplant](https://www.macroplant.com) shows your voice mail recordings, let's you play the records in demo mode. In paid mode you can export the sound files.